# Error "No column name was specified for column " " of "SOURCE" while select with case on merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select with case on merge in one of my pet projects and I ended up getting error.

I believe this is not the complete query, it is huge in number of lines and I can copy only this from the terminal. I thought maybe someone could help with this code and resolve my issue.

```
MERGE OrderDetails AS TARGET
USING
(
SELECT OrderHeader.OrderNo, SalesOrderData.[LineNo], SalesOrderData.WebOrderNo, SalesOrderData.quantity,ISNULL(SalesOrderData.BasePrice,'0') AS BasePrice,ISNULL(SalesOrderData.CustomPrice,'0') AS CustomPrice,
ISNULL(SalesOrderData.FinishingPrice,'0')AS FinishingPrice,ISNULL(SalesOrderData.NonDiscount2,'0') AS NonDiscountable, ISNULL(SalesOrderData.TotalPrice,'0') AS TotalPrice,
ISNULL(SalesOrderData.ExtendedPrice,'0') As ExtendedPrice,SalesOrderData.Category,SalesOrderData.StockNo,SalesOrderData.SSD,SalesOrderData.VerticalSS,SalesOrderData.LorH, SalesOrderData.WorB, SalesOrderData.Species,
SalesOrderData.FinishingOption, SalesOrderData.Grade, SalesOrderData.Sheen, SalesOrderData.FinishingBrand,SalesOrderData.ColorName,SalesOrderData.ColorNo,SalesOrderData.StockPaint,                        
     CASE 
      WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'TL' THEN '1.125'
      WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'RP' THEN '1.125'
      WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'CTL' THEN '1.25'
      WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'CTL-BAH' THEN '1.25'
      WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'CRP' THEN '1.25'
      WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'IRP' THEN '1.07'
      Else SalesOrderData.[SS Thickness]
    END
, SalesOrderData.BRD, SalesOrderData.TRD, SalesOrderData.CRD, SalesOrderData.CRD2, SalesOrderData.CRD3, SalesOrderData.CRP1,SalesOrderData.CRP2, SalesOrderData.CRP3, SalesOrderData.Section1, SalesOrderData.Section2,
SalesOrderData.Section3, SalesOrderData.Section4, 
    CASE
      WHEN SalesOrderData.PanelType = 'NA' THEN '-'
    Else SalesOrderData.PanelType
    END

FROM SalesOrderData
INNER JOIN OrderHeader ON SalesOrderData.WebOrderNo = OrderHeader.WebOrderNo 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON SalesOrderData.WebOrderNo = OrderDetails.WebOrderNo)
                        
AS SOURCE   
ON Source.WebOrderNo = Target.WebOrderNo
        
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN 
INSERT 
(OrderNo, [LineNo], WebOrderNo, Quantity,BasePrice, CustomPrice, FinishingPrice, NonDiscountable,TotalPrice,ExtendedPrice, Category,StockNo, SSD, VerticalSS,LorH, WorB, Species,FinishingOption, Grade, Sheen, 
FinishingBrand, ColorName,ColorNo,StockPaint,SSthick, BRD, TRD, CRD, CRD2, CRD3, CRP1Req,CRP2Req, CRP3Req, Section1, Section2, Section3, Section4,PanelType, RailConfig, ItemText6,SStype, ArchLow, ArchHigh,
LouverDirection, TrimType, TrimLouverDirection,MHLouverDirection, FCRLouverDirection,MHTR,MHCR1,MHCR2,MHCR3,UM,VBoardWidth, VBoardTotal, HBoardWidth,VBoardSpacing,ShutterComments,Custom1,Custom2,Custom3,Custom4,Custom5)
VALUES 
(Source.OrderNo,Source.[LineNo], Source.WebOrderNo, Source.Quantity,Source.BasePrice, Source.CustomPrice, Source.FinishingPrice, Source.NonDiscountable,Source.TotalPrice,Source.Source.ExtendedPrice, Source.Category,
Source.StockNo, Source.SSD, Source.VerticalSS,Source.LorH, Source.WorB, Source.Species, Source.FinishingOption, Source.Grade, Source.Sheen, Source.FinishingBrand, Source.ColorName,Source.ColorNo,Source.StockPaint,
Source.SSthick, Source.BRD, Source.TRD, Source.CRD, Source.CRD2, Source.CRD3, Source.CRP1Req,Source.CRP2Req, Source.CRP3Req, Source.Section1, Source.Section2, Source.Section3, Source.Section4,Source.PanelType,
Source.RailConfig, Source.ItemText6,Source.SStype, Source.ArchLow, Source.ArchHigh, Source.LouverDirection, Source.TrimType, Source.TrimLouverDirection,Source.MHLouverDirection, Source.FCRLouverDirection,Source.MHTR,
Source.MHCR1,Source.MHCR2,Source.MHCR3,Source.UM,Source.VBoardWidth, Source.VBoardTotal, Source.HBoardWidth,Source.VBoardSpacing,SSource.hutterComments,Source.Custom1,Source.Custom2,Source.Custom3,Source.Custom4,
Source.Custom5);
```

Comment: I didn't make a JS snippet. Someone was nice enough to eidt my question to make it more readable.

Comment: The edit was made by @01001010 and approved by the community - what is the world coming to - they added more clarification text than I'm normally comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE` expressions need aliases. You have, for example:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'TL' THEN '1.125'
  ...
  ELSE SalesOrderData.[SS Thickness]
END
,
```

It needs to be:

```
SomeMeaningfulAlias = CASE 
  WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'TL' THEN '1.125'
  ...
  ELSE SalesOrderData.[SS Thickness]
END
,
```

Or:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SalesOrderData.Category = 'TL' THEN '1.125'
  ...
  ELSE SalesOrderData.[SS Thickness]
END AS SomeMeaningfulAlias
,
```

Comment: Okay. So the alias need to be the name of the field for the INSERT statement?

Comment: @Pattie Yes, you would say `Source.SomeMeaningfulAlias`. The outer query has no idea what `Source.PanelType` is because you essentially hid that inside a `CASE` expression. Your `CASE` expression must apply the alias in one of the forms I've described.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been fighting this for a week. It worked. You are awesome!

Comment: Your suggestions got rid of my error. However, the new data from Sales Order Data Table is not merging into Order Details Table. Any idea why?

Comment: @Pattie No, I probably wouldn't be using `MERGE` for that pattern anyway. See [sqlblog.org/merge](https://sqlblog.org/merge)...